# AWS Pinpoint push notification delivery issue with iOS and Android

Tags: ios, amazon-web-services, push-notification, aws-mobilehub, aws-pinpoint

AWS pinpoint Push notifications are not working today in both platforms (iOS and Android). Actually, they worked fine yesterday. I'm using the latest AWS Pinpoint 2.5.9 SDK for iOS and 2.4.5 SDK for Android. Is there any limitations for pinpoint pushes? Are there any ways to test the push in iOS via development mode? It would be helpful if you have any ideas about this.

Comment: Not working for us either (today)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From July 19th 16:45 PDT to July 20th 10:36 PDT Pinpoint experienced issues with recurring and scheduled campaign deliverability. This resulted in campaigns not being executed and failed message delivery. The issue has been resolved and the service has recovered.

Comment: Am facing the same issue once again. Actually it works fine on July 21st, but by evening onwards it was not working. Is this still in maintenance, any idea?

Comment: For deeper insights into send issues you can enable EventStreams to see your campaign send events and the statuses on a per endpoint level.  Alternatively you can go to the Console Events Analytics tab choose "Campaign Send" as your event type and view your "campaign_send_status" distribution.

Comment: @Madhavan it looks like you have experience with aws pin point. Could you help me look at the question I am linking below, I will greatly appreciate your answer.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55226785/how-do-i-store-aws-pinpoint-messages-to-rds

Comment: @Samuel Nde I saw that link we are not using 2 way communication process and I don't have much knowledge on sql server related to that. By the way I will go through this and come back if I found anything useful.